# How do i add an error page to my react router code?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

so this is my code

```
              <Router>
                <Route path="/" component={Nav}/>
                <Route path="/" exact component={Home}/>
                <Route path="/updates" exact component={Updates} />
                <Route path="/author" exact component={Author} />
                <Route path="/" component={Footer}/>
              </Router>
```

It works completely fine i just have a slight problem with it. If i were to go to lets say Author page i can just type `/author` and it will show not only the author but the navbar and footer because i didn't make them exact on purpose but the problem is if i were to make a random link such as `./ejfjife` it will still show the navbar and footer i want to make it so if the user made up a link that doesn't exist it'll redirect them to some kind of 'this page doesn't exist' error

thank you

Answer (score 0):

If you always want your Nav and Footer to be present, they shouldn't even be listed under a `Route`.  They can exist outside your `Router`.  Then your `Home` component can take a `path="/" exact` and any other route can take the `path="/" Component={Error404}`.  Like this:

```js
<App>

  <Nav />

  <Router>
    <Route path="/" exact component={Home}/>
    <Route path="/updates" exact component={Updates} />
    <Route path="/author" exact component={Author} />
    <Route path="/" component={Error404}/>
  </Router>

  <Footer />

</App>
```